# interesting data phenomenon and why?

Tags: python

I've run a simple python command and it derives the following result. Can anyone tell me why?

```
a=[[0.12,0.35],[0.66,0.79]]
b=[[10*i,10*j] for i,j in a]
```

and I got the following result:

```
b=[[1.2, 3.5], [6.6000000000000005, 7.9]]
```

Comment: What about the output do you not understand?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: can you add to your question details about what you expected to get?

Answer (score 0):

This is simple representation "error".  Binary numbers do not represent decimal values with prefect accuracy, any more than a terminating decimal can accurately represent, say, 1/7.

0.66 is a decimal whose binary representation is just a hair high (actually, they're all going to be a little "off", but this is the only one that shows at a factor of only 10).  You can "fix" this by switching to a *decimal* data type.